# Does Flutter BLoC (flutter_bloc) have an equivalent to onDispose?

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, flutter-bloc

I have created a BLoC using flutter_bloc, on which I listen to a stream. When the parent widget gets disposed (and therefore the BLoC object), I would like to close my stream.

```
class ChatBloc extends Bloc<ChatEvent, ChatState> {
  //..bloc params..//

  ChatBloc(this.chatId) {
    this.add(MarkAsRead());
    subscription = messagesFirestoreRepository.chatMessages(chatId).listen((messages) {
      this.add(UpdateMessages(messages));
    });
  } //I WANT TO CLOSE THIS WHEN THE BLOC GETS DISPOSED OR DEINITED

  //..other stuff..//
}
```

Does flutter_bloc or 'Any' class have the equivalent of dispose or Swift's deinit?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override the `close` method:

```dart
class ChatBloc extends Bloc<ChatEvent, ChatState> {
  @override
  Future<void> close() {
    // Release resources here
    super.close();
  }
}
```